# UIAutomator. How to press "send" button on android EditText?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I'm making android app testing.
I have set text into edittext and need to press "Send" button on the keyboard. How to do that?
I have tried

```
getUiDevice().pressEnter();
```

but it doesnt work. Isnt it the thing which should simulate "send" button press?

Answer (score 0):

if you have android:imeOptions="actionSend" set then you can just add "\n" at end of the text that you are seting to edittext feild. for example:

UiObject input_edittext = new UiObject(new UiSelector().description("user name"));
input_edittext.setText("user1234\n");

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. It just adds an empty character at the end of the input